# performing mathematical operations on the query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using a query to return the total number of records x number of days that were registered... I would like to have the average too, how can I get this result?

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CAST(DataCriacao AS DATE))  AS dias, userid, COUNT(*), SUM(count(*) / dias) FROM ticket WHERE MONTH(DataCriacao) = month(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(DataCriacao) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND motivoRegistro LIKE '%Ap%' GROUP BY userid ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

expected

```
+--------+------+----------+-----+
| userid | dias | count(*) | avg |
+--------+------+----------+-----+
| root   |   10 |       50 |   5 |
+--------+------+----------+-----+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you just want division?

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CAST(DataCriacao AS DATE)) AS dias, userid, COUNT(*),
       count(*) / COUNT(DISTINCT CAST(DataCriacao AS DATE))
FROM ticket
WHERE MONTH(DataCriacao) = month(CURDATE()) AND
      YEAR(DataCriacao) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND
      motivoRegistro LIKE '%Ap%'
GROUP BY userid
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```